# Load/run/execute Chrome extension in new tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to run/execute a Chrome Extension in a new tab/window by loading the extension's code in that new tab or window?

Right now, the only way I know to get "free hosting" from Google for my Chrome extension, is to use the popup window as my main application window. That works fine, except for the fact that the popup window will close if you click on a different tab. So I think I need a different type of window as my main application window.

My only guess, is that you could set the window.location of the new tab to something like `chrome://extensions/<my-extension-id>` but that doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone alleviate my confusion? How to create a runtime for a Chrome app that isn't the popup, but isn't a native app, and isn't hosted by some web server other than Google's servers?

One thing I was thinking of was something like this:
https://gist.github.com/danharper/8364399

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve that can't be done in a casual [`background.js`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)?

Comment: It's about the UI - which window to use. The popup window is not really sufficient, but I don't really understand the alternatives.

Comment: You can use the popup for the UI and exchange any relevant information with the `background.js`. Or you can also create a simple HTML file that you can package with your extension which you can open when any heavier user interaction is needed.

Comment: yeah I explain in the question the problem with the popup

Comment: I think the solution might be: `chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')});`

Comment: Yeah like I said, load a simple HTML page you can package with your extension.

Comment: the only way I know, is with the line of code I just dropped

Comment: Simply add it to your extension, style it as you want and attach any necessary css or js files inside its code just like always and then you can use its relative path to open it with other functions inside the popup or other extension pages. For example inside a popup you can have: `window.open("example.html")` which will open it in a new tab with the URL being `chrome://extensions/<my-extension-id>/example.html`.

Comment: yeah that might work, I added an answer that seems to work

Answer (score 0):

holy crap that was harder than it needed to be.

So you eventually end up at a url like this:

```
chrome-extension://<your-extension-id>/dist/index.html
```

to programmatically load a new tab or window, use this code in your background script:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('dist/index.html')});
```

in my case my app page, is located at dist/index.html, whereas my popup page will live at popup.html.

So the popup window looks something like this:

```
x Load extension in new window
x Load extension in new tab
```

the user selects one of those, and the background.js script can call the above code to load the page, which will load the html file from your extension codebase that you so desire.

Comment: No need for `chrome.extension.getURL`, the API automatically resolves relative paths to the page path of the invoker, it's also mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create). An absolute path `/dist/index.html` would resolve to the extension root.

Comment: @wOxxOm one question for you....why does chrome.extension still point to the original extension after opening a new tab or window? that doesn't make sense to me.. any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "original extension"? Everything in the package is part of the "original" extension.

Comment: well dude think about it...when you click the chrome popup icon, that's quite different than a chrome tab just opening an html file...chrome.extension could be defined differently

Comment: It's also a page, but displayed in a small popup window. That page has an URL like chrome-extension://id/popup.html which is what makes it a part of the extension. That's why content scripts instances aren't really part of the extension because they use DOM of the page they run in, but they still can communicate via messaging with the background/popup/other pages so they can also be considered a part of the extension :-)

Comment: right, I guess whenever you load a url with the "protocol" `chrome-extension://` that's what determines most of the properties on the chrome global, etc